# Oscillation without a minimum value

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X\subset \mathbb R^n$ be a compact subset. I'm having troubles to find a counterexample of a bounded function $f:X\to\mathbb R$ which its oscillation doesn't reach a minimum value.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: you mean that the function $f$ doesn't need to be continuous?

Comment: @copper.hat I'm looking for an example of a bounded function $X\to \mathbb R$ such that its oscillation doesn't reach a minimum value. Please see my edit.

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo Please see my edit

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo no, the function doesn't need to be continuous

Comment: @user409198 Then take any function $g$ that attains its minimum value exactly *once* at $x_{min} \in X$, and define $f=g$ on $X$ except at $f(x_{min})=g(x_{min})+1\,$.

Comment: @dxiv of course! thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If your definition of oscillation at a point includes the value at the point, then you may define $f: [0,1] \rightarrow {\Bbb R}$ as follows:
$$ f (x) = \left\{ \begin{array} {ll}
   1 & {\rm if\;} x=0 \\
  x & {\rm if\;} x\in (0,1]\cap {\Bbb Q} \\
  0 & {\rm if\;} x\in [0,1]\setminus {\Bbb Q}  \end{array} \right. $$
$inf_{x\in [0,1]} \omega(f,x)=0$ is not attained.